# Solidity Contract A Calling Contract B Payable Function

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity

In the simplified (incomplete) code below, the **runIt()** function in *contract B* makes a transfer to *contract A*. This works fine, I can check the balance of *contract A* afterwards and it receives the funds fine at this stage alone.

Immediately after this transfer, the **runIt()** function in *contract B* calls the **randomEvent()** function in *contract A*. This function in *contract A* is meant to make another transfer, sending the entire *contract A* balance to *contract C* (not shown). For some reason I can never get this part to work. I tried to simplify the code by changing the target of **randomEvent()** to a wallet address instead of a contract address but I experience the same problem there. MetaMask flags the transaction as having issues and it won't process if you try.

In this code example it might seem like I'm sending funds in circles but that's just because I've simplified it for ease of explanation. Can anyone please help me figure out how I can execute a second transfer from *contract A* to *contract C*, following the receiving of funds from *contract B*? I initially tried to call the **randomEvent()** function from *contract A* directly, inside the payable function so that it fires every time it receives a transfer from anywhere. This would work perfectly fine, too, except I ran into the same issue and error. It didn't work that way, either.

I'm new to Solidity so I'm probably missing something stupid but any advice would be much appreciated. Yes, I know I'm using a very old version of Solidity, I'll eventually refactor it to something more modern.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract A {
  function () public payable {
    }

  function randomEvent() public payable {
      address wallet = 0x0000; // Random Contract C Address
      wallet.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
  }
}

contract B {
  address public platform;
  platform = 0x000; // Contract A Address
  uint someValue = 1000000; // Irrelevant Example Amount

  function runIt() public payable {
    platform.transfer(someValue); // This works fine, funds in Contract A are received.

    A ContractA = A(platform);
    ContractA.randomEvent(); // This transaction fails and won't process, funds aren't moved from Contract A to Contract C.
  }
}
```

Comment: Bumping this in hopes of any advice, please.

Comment: Did you find any solution?